# When I add a blurred background, it blurs the rest of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

All of the answers to this same question do not work for me because of the fade in animation, made with jQuery. If I put {position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0;} for both the background class and the content class, then the fade in animation doesnt work. I also tried adding {filter: none;} to everything other than the background class.

```js
$(function(){ 
  $('.intro').fadeIn('slow');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        $('.article').each( function(i){            
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){    
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);
                    
            }
            
        }); 
    
    });
    
});
```

```css
#main-container{
  height: 2000px;
    background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/43V74cv9/Screenshot-2019-03-19-at-6-29-57-PM.jpg');
  filter: blur(5px);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}


.article{
    background-color: blue;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="bg">
    <div id="main-container">
          <h1>TITLE PLACEHOLDER</h1>
      <div id="intro">intro stuff</div>
      <div class="article">other stuff</div>
        <div class="article">other stuff</div>
        <div class="article">other stuff</div>
        <div class="article">other stuff</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: _“All of the answers to this same question do not work for me”_ - sounds like you did not understand any of them to begin with, because otherwise you should know by now that you can not apply a filter to an element without affecting all its descendants …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blur filter applies to all child elements of `main-container`. Create additional container with absolute position, behind `#main-container`to which will be assigned background:

```js
$(function(){ 
  $('.intro').fadeIn('slow');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        $('.article').each( function(i){            
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
             if($(this).hasClass('animated') == false){ //if class .animated exists, skip animating
                 $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500); //animate
                 $(this).addClass('animated'); //add css class to avoid animating repeatedly 
             }
                
                    
            }
            
        }); 
    
    });
    
});
```

```css
#background-container{
 height: 2000px;
 background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/43V74cv9/Screenshot-2019-03-19-at-6-29-57-PM.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 filter: blur(5px);
 z-index: 0;
}
#main-container{
  height: 2000px;
  position:relative; /* set position other than static, so we can avoid overlapping of elements by z-index */  
  z-index: 1;
}


.article{
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="bg">
 <div id="background-container"></div>
    <div id="main-container">
          <h1>TITLE PLACEHOLDER</h1>
      <div id="intro">intro stuff</div>
      <div class="article">other stuff</div>
        <div class="article">other stuff</div>
        <div class="article">other stuff</div>
        <div class="article">other stuff</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

*Note:* I have added `position:relative` to `main-container` so `z-index` works and to avoid overlapping of `main-container` and `background-container`. 
Also, I have added classes `animated` once the `.article` appears, to avoid repeating animation every time you scroll the page.

Answer (score 1):

The main-container wraps rest of your code. Naturally, when you apply blur-filter to it, it blurs the other items that exists within the wrapper. Try to add another div as shown in the edited code with absolute positioning. This will solve your problem.

```js
$(function(){ 
  $('.intro').fadeIn('slow');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        $('.article').each( function(i){            
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){    
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);
                    
            }
            
        }); 
    
    });
    
});
```

```css
#main-container{
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
}

.main-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/43V74cv9/Screenshot-2019-03-19-at-6-29-57-PM.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(5px);
 }

.article{
    background-color: blue;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="bg">
    <div id="main-container">
      <div class="main-image"></div>
      <h1>TITLE PLACEHOLDER</h1>
      <div id="intro">intro stuff</div>
      <div class="article">other stuff</div>
        <div class="article">other stuff</div>
        <div class="article">other stuff</div>
        <div class="article">other stuff</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```